# AngularJS spinner not showing, possibly due to http.get firing too quick

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spinner, http-get

Apologies if this is duplicated with other post, but my reputation points are too low to comment on them. I have the following to show a spinner while I fire off an http get.

HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="loadRemedyData(showsitegroup.groupSelect)" 
    style="font-size:12px">
View UnScheduled WO's
<i ng-show="loading" class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin" ></i></button>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.loading = false;

$scope.loadRemedyData = function(qName) {
    //Injects scope from Remedy Database JSON
    $scope.loading = true;
    $http.get("/openremedywos?qName=" + qName)
        .then(function (response) {$scope.newdevices = response.data;});
    $scope.loading = false;
  }
```

If I comment out the last line that changes the loading flag back to false, the spinner shows and keeps running, show proves that its initializing.

Question is, with the above, I assume its not showing as it moves onto the last flag change to quickly, even though it can take up to 20-30 sec for the scope to show.

I appreciate that 20-30 sec isn't alot but I would like to have it show the  spinner to prevent impatient users from thinking its not working, by showing the in progress spinner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are not waiting for the http return before assiging the `$scope.loading` to `false`.

Try this:

```
$scope.loadRemedyData = function(qName) {
//Injects scope from Remedy Database JSON
$scope.loading = true;
$http.get("/openremedywos?qName=" + qName).then(function (response){
    $scope.newdevices = response.data;
    $scope.loading = false; // brought it inside. Where it will wait for the http to get response.
});
}
```